# Communication between the same app in different smartphones

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I would like to develop an application. It could be a game or whatever. I would have the same application in two or more devices. When one of them finish his tasks the other "client" must receive an notify that he has task to do and his datas should be updated automatically with the last changes. I guess that I would need a server in the middle where I'd save the model with the datas and send to them where the smartphones are communicating through it. It could be like a cardgame or kind of.

So,,,,
1. Two or more clients with the same application.
2. When one of them finish his task or turn, the other client should get a notify with his dates updates.

I have been looking at GCM, but I don't know if I could send complex datas through it or not,, and maybe there is a better way to make these kind of things.

Could someone give a clue where I can start??

Thank you!.

Answer (score 0):

In your architecture, you must separate out the control and data aspects of the app.

You don't need the cloud to initiate a push of the entire data. If your app on any particular device gets a notification that an update is pending, then it can initiate the download at its convenience. Just use the GCM to push a notification that some task is pending for the app.

Comment: I guess that when we're talking about "updates", it's about new datas, right?. But, what I guess it's that if I need notifications, I should use GCM and after of that, another method so that the app gets the new datas to the new situation like a call to one webservices. This call should run when the user finally start the applicacion after of see the notification. I don't know if there's a better and easy way to do it.

Comment: So just make the app download the data it wants when it boots up!